# Blank white screen is getting while swiping from one page to another in android

Tags: android

i have a problem when i try to swipe from one page to another in android, the white screen is appearing for one second while navigating from first page to second, it is coming for each and every page swiping in android...Reply me if u have any idea

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to post your code in order to get it revised.